# apt-get install pgadmin fail with libgtk2.0-0 & libwxgtk2.8.0 not configured yet

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get, pgadmin

-Edit after closing-
I try to install ruby 3 to a Server and that kind of work, but when I check out my project and try `bundle install` I get the error message, that `gem pg` needs pgadmin, that is why I asked directly for the command. In this case it is related to programming...

-- original question

I simply try to install pgadmin to an ubuntu machine, but it fails with the following Exception:

```
apt-get install pgadmin3
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pgadmin3 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 114 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up shared-mime-info (0.71-1ubuntu2) ...
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing shared-mime-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-0:
 libgtk2.0-0 depends on shared-mime-info; however:
  Package shared-mime-info is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgtk2.0-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk2.0-bin:
 libgtk2.0-bin depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.20.1-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libgtk2.0-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwxgtk2.8-0:
 libwxgtk2.8-0 depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.18.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libwxgtk2.8-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                              No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                    gadmin3:
 pgadmin3 depends on libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.10.1); however:
  Package libwxgtk2.8-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing pgadmin3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shared-mime-info
 libgtk2.0-0
 libgtk2.0-bin
 libwxgtk2.8-0
 pgadmin3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tryed alot of different stuff, but nothing helped.
Tell me if you need mor information.

Is there a way to force dpkg to accept not configured?

### Update

I tryed `update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`

and the ouptput can be found here
http://pastebin.com/9CjwLWgP

It looks like a bug without a solution, doesn't it?

When I enter `dpkg -l libc6 gdb libxml2`

it occours

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
un  gdb            <none>         (no description available)
ii  libc6          2.11.1-0ubuntu Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libxml2        2.7.6.dfsg-1ub GNOME XML library
```

**Update 2**

I installed libxml2.7.7 (see history:)

```
wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.7.tar.gz
tar -xvzf libxml2-2.7.7.tar.gz 
cd libxml2-2.7.7
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libxml2
make
sudo make install
```

But I still get an error, see http://pastebin.com/E8bNdp2G

**Update 3**
Problem solved!

here my last history:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxml2/libxml2_2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libxml2_2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb 
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install pgadmin3
```

Now i can use postgresql for my rails application :D

Thank you Ariel!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run: `update-mime-database -V /usr/share/mime` and show us the output.

Looks like someone else has encountered this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shared-mime-info/+bug/775619

And it seems to be an old bug too: http://pastebin.com/fcw2XQDY

And it's a perennial problem going back to 2006: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/desktop-bugs/2006-September/049391.html

I would contact ubuntu using the first link I gave you. If they can't help you, you may be able to force dpkg to consider shared-mime-info as configured even if it's not.

But first try the command I gave you, maybe it will give useful info. (That is the command that is crashing.)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, and I'll contact ubuntu.But it also would be nice to know how to force dpkg to say "its configured" does anyone know that?

Comment: You could edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/shared-mime-info.postinst and comment out the line that calls update-mime-database. Do it at your own risk though, it won't cause immediate problems, but you do need to figure out why that command fails. Otherwise something else will certainly break.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I have absolutly no idea why this command break and I'm not sure if there is a way to seperate the problem.

Comment: Well, run the command manually like I said at the top of my answer and see what it says.

Comment: Please see my last update to my question, i cross my fingers that it helps to analyse the problem.

Comment: Try `strace update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` copy the output to http://bastebin.com and add a comment with the link to the paste. Maybe it will help, I can't say for sure.

Comment: You can find the output from the command there: http://pastebin.com/9CjwLWgP

Comment: @Tobias Upgrade libxml2 to 2.7.7

Comment: thank you, I'll try it in the evening and keep you updated :)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help, see the result from apt-get install pgadmin3 http://pastebin.com/E8bNdp2G

Comment: @Tobias Did you upgrade libxml2? I don't see any mention of that in the pastebin.

Comment: I installed it in the way I describe it in my question (See Update 2) I thought about updating my question itself would help others to see what I did. Is there a way to check the version? By the way thy Ariel :)

Comment: @Tobias No, no, don't install things manually on ubuntu! Uninstall that, and install the .deb package properly from ubuntu repositories. Go here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/libxml2 and download at least 2.7.7 - but it's better to do it via apt-get. I notice you have 114 packages not upgraded - it's quite possible libxml2 is one of them. Do `apt-get install libxml2` and see what version it gives you. Try also `apt-get install libxml2=2.7.7.dfsg-4ubuntu0.2` If you have to, download the .deb file and `dpkg -i filename.deb`

Comment: If you are still running lucid, you need to upgrade to maverick.

Comment: I cant belev it, i made it :D
I think apt-get upgrade solved my problem, but before that i downloaded libxml2.7.7 and used dpkg -i filename.deb 
Thank you so much!!!

now i only have to configute the gemfile pg, but this is another story :D